# Responsive List of Items with % width

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a responsive layout where the sidebar drop below the content in mobile.

In full width the list of items in the sidebar are at 100% width. So its like one item in one row...

In mobile I want 2 items in 1 row... by setting the width of each item to 50%. Not sure where I am going wrong...

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/nN6Zt/

```
#item {width:100%;background:#eeefff;}
#list_item{display:block;min-height:60px;border:1px solid #333}

@media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width: 768px)
{
#item {width:50%;}
h1 {font-size:180%;line-height:120%;}
}
```

Comment: An added suggestion is to use classes instead of IDs.  Multiple elements should not use the same ID.

Comment: @TomPietrosanti Agree captain, just for the fiddle a quick html :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given 50% width to item, give it to list-item

**Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/nN6Zt/2/**

```
#item {width:100%;
background:#eeefff;
float:left;
}

#list_item {
width: 49%;
float: left; 
}
```

49% to avoid breakage.

Or you can use `box-sizing:border-box;` as Tom mentioned.

```
#list_item {
width: 50%;
float: left; 
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: You can use `box-sizing: border-box` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to use `50%` without needing mystical adjustments to avoid line-breaking.  Also, it's worth pointing out that you have to counteract the `display: block` either with `float` (as Surjith has done), or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @TomPietrosanti -  which is safer ? IE considered.

Comment: Thanks @TomPietrosanti I've upadted the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/nN6Zt/13/

Comment: IE8+ supports `inline-block` well, though there is a whitespace issue (http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).  `float` will give you the best all around support.

Comment: IE8+ also supports `box-sizing: border-box`.  You'll need prefixes for `-webkit-` and `-moz-`, but otherwise should be fine.  (You can get this box-sizing in earlier IE versions, but it's kind of hacky - have to get into quirks mode).

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the css for `div` but `a` doesn't have any `css` assigned to it....since your end child element is a `a` tag, its more semantic to assign a styling to it for all media queries use!

amend this s to your css for `@media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width: 768px) {}` (or whichever was required to bring in the effects)

```
 #item > a#list_item {
        display:inline-block;
        width:48%; /* to avoid any clash for breaking */
    }
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nN6Zt/5/)